# Can I directly split the project archive in kdenlive?

Tags: samba, archive, pipe, kdenlive

I created a huge project in Kdenlive. Now, I wanted to archive it and then move the archive onto a Samba share with almost 50 GB free space, because I'm running low on free disk space on my main PC (9.6 GiB free). The problem is, that Kdenlive shows me a final archive size of 15.7 GiB, and that will never fit in the free space I have. Now you could say : Why not just directly archive the project onto the Samba share ? Well, that's not possible either, as the Samba share does not let me create files bigger than 2 or 4 GB.
Now my 2 questions are: Can I tell Kdenlive somehow to split the archive up into 1 GB chunks (like `split zipfile.zip -b 1G ZIPCHUNKS`) ? If that's not possible, can maybe let Kdenlive archive the project into a pipe which then could be split into chunks from the terminal (something like `cat pipefile > split - -b 1G ZIPCHUNKS`) ?

UPDATE: I found a solution for now by enabling `Only archive proxy clips if available` which reduced the files size to 7.7 GiB. Still, I would like to know if the above is possible !

Comment: With named pipes: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451362/split-output-and-rejoin-again-with-named-pipes-on-linux, but I don't think KDEnlive will be able to write to a named pipe. Still, you may be able to process your actual project files something like this: tar, then split the tar and send the pieces over to the share.

Comment: @vanadium well, the problem was that I was not able to store the archive as a whole first, so I need to use named pipes.